# Deleting repeating records in SAS

Tags: sas, repeat

I have a table that will be loaded into an oracle database.
I need to delete repeating values without changing the order of the data.
There are 5 possible records for each group. 
1. The empty rows need to be removed.
2. Duplicated Names need to be removed,so only distinct names appear.
3. The data can't be reordered.

```
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security
3   
4   
5   SSA  1996
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security 
3   
4   
5   SSA 1997
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security
3   
4   
5   SSA  -1998
1   Commingled Data
2   Statistical Administrative 
3   
4   
5   StARS 2000
1   Federal
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1099
5   Master File - TY 1997 (1099/IRMF)
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1099
5   Master File - TY 1998 (1099/IRMF)
1   State
2    Wage
3   Indiana
4   
5    Indiana - 1990Q1-2005Q2
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1040
5    TY 2003 (1040/IMF) 1% File
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal
4   1040
5   TY 2003 (1040/IMF) Cycles 1-39
```

Comment: What is a 'repeated row'?  What is your output?  And what are you trying?

Comment: The repeatable row is usually row 1,  row 1 is comingled data, federal also repeats row 2 also repeats, and sometimes row 3 does too.. I'm trying first.last function, also coalescec and selfjoin and with an offset.

Comment: Can you : first step =>  do a Select distinct to select distinct variables only, and then second step => delete a row if all the variables are missing?

Comment: Ok, I did that before, but it messed up the order. I need the order to remain unchanged after I delete dups and missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for the HASH object.  If you use `multidata:'n'` and the `ref` method, it will check if the record is already in the hash table and, if not, add it - but not add duplicates.

Here I add `rownum` so to be able to return to the original sorted order, since hash tables are binary trees and do not have a natural order unless you impose it.

```
data have;
input @1 line $50.;
datalines;
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security
3   
4   
5   SSA  1996
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security 
3   
4   
5   SSA 1997
1   Commingled Data
2   Social Security
3   
4   
5   SSA  -1998
1   Commingled Data
2   Statistical Administrative 
3   
4   
5   StARS 2000
1   Federal
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1099
5   Master File - TY 1997 (1099/IRMF)
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1099
5   Master File - TY 1998 (1099/IRMF)
1   State
2    Wage
3   Indiana
4   
5    Indiana - 1990Q1-2005Q2
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal 
4   1040
5    TY 2003 (1040/IMF) 1% File
1   Federal 
2    Treasury
3   Internal
4   1040
5   TY 2003 (1040/IMF) Cycles 1-39
;;;;
run;

data _null_;
  set have end=eof;
  rownum = _n_;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(ordered:'n', multidata:'n');
    h.defineKey('line');
    h.defineData('line', 'rownum');
    h.defineDone();
  end;
  if not missing(substr(line,3)) then rc = h.ref();
  if eof then do;
    h.output(dataset:'want');
  end;
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by rownum;
run;
```

Comment: Joe, Thank you ! No one at work could solve this problem.  You're amazing. Thanks again